# Trying to create file

Tags: file, creation

Trying to do this code

```
         try {
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile()
                file.exists()
            }

            val out = FileOutputStream(file)
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
            out.flush()
            out.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

But getting

> java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Very strange behaviour

Comment: You need to post a minimal, reproducible example if you want to be helped. This isn't reproducible.

Comment: do I need to ask permission?ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StationActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

Comment: I don't understand, copy it to sample project and your will understand

Comment: Can't. `file` and `finalBitmap` don't exist.

Comment: file is val file = File(myDir, fname) and fun saveImage(finalBitmap: Bitmap):File {

Comment: the answer 
`val file1 = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + File.separator + "test.png")
        file1.createNewFile()
        file1.exists()

        val out = FileOutputStream(file1)
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
        out.flush()
        out.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
    val file1 = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + File.separator + "test.png")
    file1.createNewFile()
    file1.exists()

    val out = FileOutputStream(file1)
    finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
    out.flush()
    out.close()
```